# JSON string convert to javascript object with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get data in a URL like "/system/people/3", how can I convert (see bottom json) with jQuery and make something like: `$(".name").(data.name);` I need to place it in a div...

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "George X.",
    "description": "test 1sdfasdfasdf",
    "birthday": "2017-10-01 00:00:00"
}
```

Comment: Using the JSON you gave us, can you post an _actual_ example of the output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you want specifically jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    $(".name").html(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString); // parse JSON string
$('.name').html(data.name); // select element and update its content
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the response received with `JSON.parse`

`var data = JSON.parse(profileResponse);`

Or you can send the request with `$.getJSON` which will automatically parse the response and will be available as JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()` function

`var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');`

Comment: It is possible to place url to get data?

Comment: hitting a url may cause async operation which can be best handdled by AJAX. You should use AJAX for getting data from the url